# ¿Como previsualizar nombres de archivos que coge un input file?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Como puedo mostrar los nombres de archivos que coge un `input file` o `multiple` y personalizarlos en `css`. lo que quiero conseguir es antes de subir los archivos al servidor que me aparezcan todos los archivos en una lista por si quiero borrar alguno. No se si lo tengo que hacer con `jquery` `php` o como..... adjunto una imagen.

```
<div class="add">
 <label for="file-input">
  <img src="img/add.png" width="35" height="35" alt="add">
 </label>
 <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple=""/>
</div>
<!-- fin del add -->
<div id="archivos">
 <div id="archivo">
  <div class="nombre_archivo">nombre del archivooooooooooooooooooooo
  <span class="tooltiptext"><?php echo $tooltip; ?> </span>
 </div>
 <div class="tamano_archivo">30mb</div>
 <div class="eliminar_archivo"><img src="img/eliminar.png" width="20" height="20" alt="eliminar"></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué cosas has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo, obviamente se puede mejorar. Tus archivos se almacenan temporalmente en la variable **archivosParaSubir**.

```js
var inputFile = $("#inputFile");
var listaDeArchivos = $("#listaDeArchivos");
var archivosParaSubir = [];

function actualizarListaDeArchivos() {
  let listaHtml = archivosParaSubir.map(function(item, index) {
    return `<li>
      ${item.name} 
      <button data-index="${index}" class="file-list-eliminar">Eliminar</button>
    </li>`;
  });
  listaDeArchivos.html(listaHtml);
}

inputFile.on('change', function(e) {
  let files = e.target.files;
  
  if(files.length == 0) return;
  
  files = Array.from(files);
  archivosParaSubir = files;
  actualizarListaDeArchivos();
  $(this).val('');
});

$(document).on("click", ".file-list-eliminar", function() {
  let index = $(this).data('index');
  archivosParaSubir.splice(index, 1);
  actualizarListaDeArchivos();
});
```

```css
#listaDeArchivos li{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="" id="inputFile" multiple>

<ul id="listaDeArchivos">
</ul>
```